# Accessing one text 

Tags: asp.net

ASp.NET application.
In button click i am accessing one text file and reading content.

while both users clicking this button at a time deadlock will occurs so how to handle this i want to read each user one by one can any one suggest method to handle.
  i am looking to handle with waithandle events so can any one give a code sample for above scenario.

Comment: What does your code for reading these files look like? Simple file reads probably shouldn't be causing a deadlock.

Comment: perhaps consider using the Singleton pattern?
http://www.codersource.net/microsoft-net/c-advanced/implementing-the-singleton-pattern-in-c.aspx